# Relative path converter MAC->Windows, Windows->MAC in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a more clever way to convert MAC->Windows, Windows->MAC relative paths rather than taking a string and replacing tildas to dots and slashes to backslashes?

Answer (score 0):

You can do all this using [Path Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Path.aspx) from System.IO namespace.

```
Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
```

It provides a platform-specific character used to separate directory levels in a path string that reflects a hierarchical file system organization.

```
Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar
```

It provides a platform-specific alternate character used to separate directory levels in a path string that reflects a hierarchical file system organization.

```
Path.PathSeparator
```

A platform-specific separator character used to separate path strings in environment variables.